# I'm not seeing review queue notifications (red dot) or +5's or +10's for reputation in Space SE - how to further investigate?

Tags: bug, top-bar

For background see [Is the SXSE review queue (and new reputation indicator) now broken?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/916/12102).

In short, with the new navigation bar in Space SE, I'm not seeing the red dot when there are items in the review queue that are available for me, and I'm rarely seeing the `+5`'s or `+10`'s that should happen when my Q's or A's are up-voted. I do see some accumulated during periods of being logged out, but during periods of being logged in I only see the `+2`'s when I accept an answer, not rep from up-votes of Q's or A's.

What can I do to help determine if there is a bug, or something else is going on? Has the behavior changed, perhaps an additional delay?

Comment: How many items are in the review queue? There's a threshold for each one at which the red dot turns on. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/284336

Comment: @Catija I remember there being one item in one category and two items in a second category, total of three. And I've never seen a gray dot. I'll keep an eye on that now, thank's very much for the link!

Comment: Regarding not seeig +5's and +10's, could it have to be with the bounties you offered that mean -100 and you don't see +X's until you regain those 100 points?

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks! I have had several bounties in place for a week now. Then some points overcame the total, then yesterday I added another. Ah, if that's how it works, then that's probably precisely what's happening. In view of both comments, I'm thinking I'll just delete this question in about 15 minutes. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I guess this is the problem, but you can wait and confirm if you get notifications when you overcome the amount of points of the bounty

Comment: @fedorqui it looks like I just rolled over the latest bounty, and I'm seeing them again. All's well in this case.

Comment: If nobody chooses to post an answer here (based on these comments) I will eventually, but someone with a better understanding of these features may be able to explain better than I can. The link to the red-dot/gray-dot thresholding is a clear enough resolution for me, and the serial bounties explains the "missing" rep notifications. I noticed that they do appear on pages where I'm logged in to other SE sites, so I can have different `+N` values shown on different pages.

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that, while these both involve the top bar, you actually have two questions here.

Comment: @Catija *Wasn't clear they were separate until after solved*. Since they both involved behavior of the navigation bar in a single SE site *that seemed to start after the recent navigation bar upgrade*, I felt there was a good chance they were related, so better to keep them together while still asking this [definitely different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303425/303080) separately. It turns out they are not, but it looks like they were both solved within 1 hour of the original post in comments. I don't think there is any "problem" here that keeping them together is a "part of."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the noted behavior of both the review queue and new reputation flags in the navigation bar appeared to start after the new bar was installed, the explanations are different.

**Review Queue:**

As noted in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303424/#comment986543_303424), the review queue "red dot" as well as "gray dot" flags are now controlled by a thresholding algorithm as noted in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/284336) and related comments. There can be *a *few items for a user to review in the queue even though no the user sees no flag. This algorithm might be subject to further refinement.

**New Reputation:**

As noted in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303424/#comment986545_303424), the OP had initiated a sequence of bounties in one SE site, and the algorithm for new reputation flags stops displaying until the accumulated reputation exceeds the amount subtracted by the bounty. OP confirmed in comment that this is in fact what happened and flags began after new rep exceeded most recent bounty.