# Unusual behavior logging in to stackexchange.com only (not other SE sites)

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, sign-up

When I am logged in to one SE site, then type the url for another derivative SE site in a new tab, I'm already logged in there as usual.

However, when I type `stackexchange.com` I see the page not logged in.

Curiously though, if I click Log In, I get what looks like the Sign Up page.

And if I click Sign Up, I get a white page with a long url as text:

THe page's url is `https://stackexchange.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com` and the text shown on the page (I've truncated it in case there might be some security reveal in the code: `https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form?affId=11&background=transparent&callback=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2fusers%2fauthenticate&color=black&nonce=%2brsQWgAAAADlmwDRpG5zEQ%3d%3d&openid.sreg.requested=email&signupByDefault=true&onLoad=loaded&authCode=u%2bdDP1cFtRe5N13hdCOFt6EOZK2w5371%2bLZFRpDf0jtqjwV24gUVxhe%2fE1OUr52WthdUSh3FCX one hundred characters deleted`

---

Screen shot of what looks like a sign up page that appears when I click **Log In**:

> [image]

Screen shot of white page with url text that appears when I click **Sign Up** (truncated):

> [image]

Comment: This seems to be related. [I clicked the log-in link and I got a page saying, "Do you already have an account on one of these sites? You can use that to log on here!"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61242/303080) I don't understand what's happening, but is this in fact the expected behavior for someone already logged in to other SE sites?

Comment: Sort of. se.com is weird in a number of ways and this is one of them. If you were to "log in" with the same credentials you use on Q&A sites, it should set you up with a "profile" on se.com that doesn't do a heck of a lot. In fact, we're going to be removing user profiles on that site in the near future. Having said *that*, showing a plain page with the affiliate URL when you click "sign up" is not the intended behaviour. I'm gonna retag your question to [bug] and try to figure out what's going on there next week.

Comment: @AdamLear OK thanks for the info! Sounds like the situation is in good hands. Marking as duplicate makes sense, unless it somehow neutralizes the visibility of the `bug` tag.