# Can the review-needed indicator be based on votes about to age away, rather than total tasks?

Tags: discussion, design, review, vote-to-close, top-bar

As a moderator, I generally ignore the close votes queue for the reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259805/875262), on the (apparently false) assumption that if a review queue requires attention, then it will turn red.  However, it turns out that on the low-volume site that I moderate, many review tasks simply age away without warning.  There are apparently few high-rep users actively reviewing posts on the site, so some close votes end up wasted.

The review queue's functionality has a long and complicated history that I won't pretend to fully understand (just too much to read...).  From what I did read, the [review-needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/875262) (red circle) indicator appears to be based on total tasks in the queue, rather than the queue needing attention.

Options that I'm currently aware of:

- One way to handle review queue problems in general, including votes aging away, is the proposal for [3-vote closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/875262).  This won't help with tasks having fewer close votes, or for sites that don't adopt this threshold.
- Another way is to change the color of [grey circles to red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/875262) on the site.  I'm unsure what the benefit of this is supposed to be, as this would imply that the reasons I currently ignore the close vote queue are invalid.  My preference would be to only intervene when necessary, after other users have had their say - ie, just before review tasks age away.
- Another is manually checking for aged away votes [using the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304127/875262) or the [close votes tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days).  However, this has several drawbacks: (1) This is only really useful to moderators, as other users would have to start the review process all over again; (2) questions are not closed in a timely manner this way; (3) closing posts this way makes it look like they were hammered, while this is what I'm trying to avoid.

My question then is: **Would it be possible to have the review-needed indicator be based on votes about to age away, rather than total tasks?**  I think this would be ideal.

One complication I foresee is that if the review-required indicator was based on aging tasks, then it would make sense to prioritize review tasks based on their age.  However, the [current priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/875262) apparently gives advantage to newer, rather than older tasks.

Comment: On the small site I moderate, I have never seen the dot turn red for the queue that really needs it (close votes, currently at 13, sometimes higher). When the dot is red, it just means there are 2-3 suggested edits instead of 0. (At least that's been my observation since I started really paying attention to it a few months ago.)

Comment: @Laurel on your site the dot isn't permanently red all year-round with an empty queue?

Comment: @bad_coder Nope. Right now all there are only grey dots in the dropdown, and it shows two queues as empty. If you're seeing that, could it be that you're a regular user who's reviewing a lot, but not too few other users review enough to get items off the queue?

Comment: @Laurel Yes I review a lot on that site (not that he site has many review items), but if one queue is empty for a few weeks should it constantly show the red dot?