# How can we check how often questions sent to the close queue age out?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, data-explorer

My site is dealing with a rather long close vote review queue and we believe reviews are regularly ageing out. We want to address the problem in Meta and motivate it with stats over time about how frequently this happens, but I don't see any button that tells us this. Is there one? Or is there/can there be a query that gives this information?

I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304127/847707) with a [couple](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/768038/aged-away-reviews-on-potentially-bad-questions?MinReviewTasks=3) of [queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/768036/aged-away-reviews) which were named to suggest they find questions that aged away in the queue, but they include noise, like questions that are still in the close queue, and questions that have never been in the close queue.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I had a query that did it. I used it as part of the 3-vote close tests... but it's not useful in public SEDE, it requires the internal instance. If you can get a CM's attention, they should be able to find the query as it's documented internally in the process for determining whether a site should have the number of votes required to close lowered.

Comment: @Catija So a CM would be able to find it and run it for me, then give me back the data, but I wouldn't be able to run it myself?

Comment: You could see if someone here could come up with a similar query on public SEDE but it's not gonna be me. I'm clueless and didn't write the query myself. But the data doesn't change. It's generally pretty stable and I tend to look at least two weeks out for the last 3-6 months because that prevents stuff still in the queue from showing up and throwing off numbers. I think the issue is that the query relies at least partially on flags and I don't think public SEDE has flags and I'm not sure whether it has close votes or not.

Comment: You can see what the query results look like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqli0m.png) - these were the results on ELU, actually. There should be a Q&A on the mod team that explains how a mod can request the site setting be changed from 5 to 3. Also, I apparently asked this same question back in 2017, before I was a CM https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304126/how-can-i-find-out-if-close-votes-and-reviews-are-aging-out-due-to-low-usership There are some answers there that may help a bit.

Comment: The image comes from my question here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370373/three-vote-close-reopen-test-results Also, I swear there's a public post about how to request it but I can't find it right now. :/

Comment: Wow, sorry, I didn't actually check the link in your question to see that it's actually my question from 2017. Based on standards, I'm guessing this question may get closed as a duplicate but... who knows. :)

Comment: @Catija Thanks for all this Catja. And thanks for sticking around here ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/questions/2955/2957#2957 is the relevant mod teams question I believe