# Why is the review-needed indicator red for an empty queue on ELL?

Tags: bug, review

I just noticed that the Close Votes review-needed indicator is red for me on ELL:

[image: Close Votes Queue w/ Red Review-Needed Indicator]

When I click on it, however, it shows that the queue has been cleared:

[image: Empty Close Votes Queue]

I've read the explanation about how the review-needed indicators work, but I didn't see anything that could explain what's happening:

[How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)

I've tried refreshing the page in Firefox, and I've tried loading the page in Chrome, all with the same results.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The indicators have never been remotely accurate.

Comment: @curiousdannii is correct. So far I've never seen the indicators working properly, and most likely they never will, as it's too complicated to develop and require too much resources from SE.

Comment: The indicators work perfectly the way they are designed to work. The answer currently provided by Robert London explains exactly what is happening - it's meant to do this.

Comment: @Nij even if it works as designed, if it's designed such that it is misleading 80+% of the time then it's still a broken design.

Comment: @curiousdannii it is only an issue on small sites, and the large site brings in the money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have reviewed items in the queue recently e.g. [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/close/70531) but as I write this answer there's only been one review on that post, which was yours, so it still needs other people to review to clear it from the queue.

What you're seeing is that the icon does not customise for your situation. It says that there are items in the queue even though you are the one person with sufficient rep who cannot do anything more about that.

Sonic adds the following useful information in a [comment](/posts/comments/1006693):

> This also happens for users between 2,000 and 5,000 rep for the suggested edits queue: the red dot shows up even when the only pending edits are tag wiki edits, which these users can't review (so when they click, the queue shows up as "empty").

Comment: This also happens for users between 2,000 and 5,000 rep for the suggested edits queue: the red dot shows up even when the only pending edits are tag wiki edits, which these users can't review (so when they click, the queue shows up as "empty").

Comment: +1. This issue affects even when you skip an item. It also doesn't discriminate based on reputation as it affects Moderators equally.

Comment: I see this all the time now - ever since the new, more verbose (with popups etc.) version of the reviewing UI. I **systematically** see both *Low Quality* and *Suggested Edits* with the bright red dot, and when I pick them the queue is empty. I've now stopped looking at a queue anytime it has that red dot (instead of the light gray dot). This is a GIANT step backward, IMO. I've systematically checked every review queue for the site I frequent, and I been doing so several times a day, everyday. NO MORE. NO MORE phony red-dot queues, for me. I think this META "question" deserves more attention.