# Review indicator light is on, but the queue is cleared

Tags: bug, review

[image: Image of the "This queue has been cleared!" message at the end of the First Questions review queue, with the Review Queues dropdown opened, displaying an indicator light next to "First questions"]

I have this bug or problem it shows that there is something to review and when I click there is nothing even If I reload or exit and enter the site it still shows the red dot.

Comment: Have you reviewed some first questions already?

Comment: @RobertLongson no

Comment: Probably [blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the review-needed indicator red for an empty queue on ELL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308911/why-is-the-review-needed-indicator-red-for-an-empty-queue-on-ell)

Comment: Did you recently hit the back button?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov no, i just entered the site