# Why is there sometimes a dot on the review tab when there's nothing in the queues?

Tags: support, review, top-bar

I oftentimes have a dot on the review queues tab, normally indicating that there's stuff to review in the queues, yet nothing is available for reviewing, in both main and meta sites.

What does it mean when there's a dot on the review tab yet there's no review to perform in the queues?

Comment: The dot isn't personalized, as in, it doesn't take into account if there are reviews available for you, only that the review queue has a number of items above a threshold. This is by design, due to performance.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, it seems I didn't type the right words when looking for a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you're ahead of the game and already reviewed everything in the queue. The indicator isn't customized to you beyond recognizing which queues you have access to. As such, active reviewers may have this happen from time to time.

So there is, unfortunately, a bit of noise in the signal. Jon discusses this a bit in his announcement about the feature the very last paragraph [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly).

> Finally, all active tasks are counted for each queue when determining if a queue is in “danger”. Thus, there may be times when the indicator will light up but you’ll be unable to do anything about it—for example, if you’ve already done all the reviews you’re allowed to do for the current day in that queue, or if all the items to be reviewed are your own work.