# Review queue full with no posts

Tags: bug, review

For many months the Review Queue list at the [Portuguese Language SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/) had been showing me the "Low Quality Posts" as very busy (with the red dot), but when I visit the queue, the list is empty.

[image] [image]

It's been [answered](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/334/2764) at the Portuguese Meta that the queue indeed has posts, but probably only ones on which I have already voted, so they aren't visible to me any more. The latter is expected behavior, but then the queue list shouldn't show itself as busy either - I consider that a bug (or at least ill-adjusted thresholds).

I know the system [cannot be perfect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/369732), but right now it's really only getting people to ignore the queue completely.

**Update**: right now it's back to normal, after a local mod emptied the queue. This probably means it's not a solution, just a temporary respite.

[image]

Comment: I bet 20 points on "stafusa uses tag filter for the queue".

Comment: @Tom Nah, I don't even know how to do that. Besides the site is very quiet, a handful of questions and answers per day at most, so little reason really for using filters.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your queue?

Comment: @Tom It's the usual "This queue has been cleared!" message, but right now I'm not getting the red notification any more, no idea why. I suppose that makes it harder to troubleshoot... :-/

Comment: @Tom Added the screenshot anyway.

Comment: @RobertLongson For *months* on end?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the site meta to see whether any of the moderators there can shed any light on it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I even linked their [answer](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/334/2764) in my post here - they say the queue is not empty, but probably with only post I've voted on already.

Comment: @RobertLongson But it was good you suggested to look at the queue history: now I saw the local mod who answered my post there proceeded to clear up the queue, that's why right now it's fine again to me. But then it's likely not a solution, just a temporary respite.

Comment: This is a known problem. What that dot indicates is that there are a lot of questions in the queue. The reason you're not seeing them, is that on your end they're cleared. This makes sense since multiple people need to take a look at those questions, not just you. If enough people clear "their queue", the queue will be actually cleared. Or if a moderator does it, since a moderator vote in a queue will take it out of the queue.

Comment: You need to encourage other people on that site to review. That's something only that site can address itself really.

Comment: The site has been in beta for a long time, we're trying to grow, but as long it's not big enough (and growth is very slow), it's certainly *not* desired behavior to have it constantly indicating there are reviews to be done to those who can't do anything about it.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's indeed very related, but I'd say not an exact duplicate - in my case I won't be able to help later on, since it's not that I've used up my votes for the day, but that I've done my part for the posts waiting for further reviews.

Comment: There is no such thing "very busy" - even with one item in the queue, the red dot will appear. You don't see the item(s) in the queue because you already reviewed them. The list of "items you can review" is loaded when you visit the review page, but it's too expensive (resource wise) to load it on every page load anywhere, so the top bar can't know you don't have items left to review, hence the confusion.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou So what's the difference between the red and the grey circles?

Comment: @stafusa oops. I was reading some old post, yes you're right - there is also grey. Still, the reasoning stands - there are items in the queue (even five), and you can't review any of them (e.g. you already reviewed, or it's one of your own posts, etc) hence you see it as empty.