# Notification for new review queue items in top bar

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

Change the color of the icon in the top bar to green when a new review comes up.

[image]

Comment: This violates [accessibility guidelines](//www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/use-of-color.html). Also: _why_? This doesn’t fit the design language of Stack Exchange. Please see [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](/q/44188/289905).

Comment: it helps to notice that there are new review

Comment: And the [red dot](//i.stack.imgur.com/TyRH5.png) doesn’t? How is a green coloration better?

Comment: i don't get any red dot

Comment: On SO the thing would be green 100% of the time. On other sites it probably matters only if there are only a couple of reviewers. I can't see how this would be beneficial. It probably is a UX feature that gets unshipped by Aaron after 6 to 8, if it ever gets implemented.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Not exactly. See: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/348196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We already have a red dot indicating there are more reviews than normal:

[image]

It's not feasible to reliably notify individual users of new review tasks, because their availability depends on various factors:

- your reputation (some queues require more reputation than others)
- whether you've interacted with the post already or not
- how many reviews you already did in a particular queue
- if it's your own post or somebody else's
- if you've used your maximum daily up- and downvotes or close votes
- ...

As for an alternative solution, years ago I frequently used a userscript [Review Stalker Reloaded](https://stackapps.com/q/6869/34061); I'm not sure if it still works, or if there are other options.

Comment: [Redwolf Programs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/388685/redwolf-programs) has created [Generic Review Tool](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/blob/main/generic-review-tool.user.js). Currently, it's only configured to work on Code Golf, but I believe it should be simple to modify it to work on other sites

Comment: [Generic Review Tool 1.2.1](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/generic-review-tool.user.js) now has support for all sites!