# Desktop notifications for review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications

I know we have desktop notifications for chat, but can we get desktop notifications for review queues? I want to participate in more review tasks for some of the Stack Exchange communities I'm a member of such as Puzzling, Arqade, Code Review, etc.

However, due to these communities having less traffic, review tasks are *seemingly* far and few between. I'm constantly on my computer writing code, so I have the opportunity to participate in review queues throughout the day, but unfortunately, I forget to refresh my browser window and often miss out on potential tasks I could assist with.

I'm wondering if we could get desktop notifications for review queues as an *opt-in* feature, similar to chat's desktop notifications?

Comment: This seems moot to me. If people are reviewing quick enough that you have a hard time finding something in the queue, then the system is working as well as it can be; a desktop notification won't improve it. If the queue is bogged down and behind such as on SO, a desktop notification could certainly be a way to annoy people into reviewing, but it won't help someone who's looking for something to review... because the queue's always there with more stuff to do.

Comment: @KevinB I wouldn't say it's quick enough that I have a hard time, more like I'm slow enough that I have a hard time. My problem is remembering to check. Though I was recently directed to a [userscript](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/blob/main/generic-review-tool.user.js) that could help me.

Answer (score 5):

It's great that you want to help moderating some of the sites in the network. However, the principle behind the review queues is that they propose actions which need to be done within a couple of hours or a few days. Not the kind of please-react-ASAP actions notifications are meant for. If a site doesn't offer many review opportunities for you, it's a good sign: it means there are enough reviewers in the community to share the workload, with the additional benefit of having a diverse team looking at the items, instead of just a single user, irrespective of how good a reviewer that user is.

That said, there are user scripts which provide similar functionality. There is a [Generic Review Tool](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/blob/main/generic-review-tool.user.js) which I learned of [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369000/notification-for-new-review-queue-items-in-top-bar/369002#comment1231069_369002); I haven't checked it out yet (holidays...) but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that other people often get to review queues pretty quickly - there's a fair chance that by the time you notice and react to a notification (don't forget it's not just you getting the notification, it's everyone) someone else will have got their first and claimed that review for their own gamification (or to improve the quality of the SE network, whichever reason floats your boat).

In essence, many of the notifications will be fake news.

The chat and other notifications just continue to go up because they're not being resolved in the same way.

Comment: This is an absolutely fair point, and something I'm *personally* okay with, though I can see why others wouldn't be. There's always a chance that someone else could get to it first, but they already do  so I wouldn't be any more disappointed than I already am lol